# ¿Por que lanza estos errores, unos en funciones fetch, y otros de llamado a función de conexión, dependiendo como intente conectar?

Tags: php, mysqli

```html
<?php
//////Intentaba abrir una pagina dinamica que mostrara los periodos,
//al tratar de invocar esta función desde este archivo, y creando la 
//conexión con la bd, lanza lo siguiente: haciendo conexion d 2 formas

// Al dejar la primera forma de conexion:
//Warning: mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in 30
//Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_all() on null in 31
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Al dejar la segunda forma de conexion:
//Fatal error: Cannot redeclare conectar() (previously declared in C:\xampp\htdocs\cebProcedular\Model\Model_Alumno.php:14) in C:\xampp\htdocs\cebProcedular\Model\Model_Alumno.php on line 18
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 require 'Model_Depto.php'; //forma de conexion 1: archivo externo

$conexion = conectar();  
$desconectar = desconectar();
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 //forma de conexion 2: funciones 
 /*
  $conexion=null;

 function conectar()
{
 //14 global $conexion; 
   $conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','vasco');
   mysqli_set_charset($conexion, 'utf8');  
   return $conexion;
 //18   }

function desconectar()
{
    global $conexion;
    mysqli_close($conexion);  //cerrando conexion
}
*/
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   function muestraPeriodos()  //funcion
   {
          global $conexion;
/*30*/        $respuesta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM periodos");
/*31*/         return $respuesta->fetch_all(); 
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes dos errores dependiendo de qué forma de conectarte uses.

El primer error apunta a que no se establece correctamente la conexión a la base de datos por algún motivo y por falta de código de detección de errores no eres consciente de ello, dejando en un valor `false` la variable `$conexion` o bien la consulta no se realiza por algún motivo y tampoco eres consciente de ello.

El segundo (`Fatal error: Cannot redeclare conectar()`) está provocado por definir en dos archivos la función `conectar()`. Revisa bien tus archivos para no repetir la definición de esa función en varios puntos.

Editado para mostrarte una forma de realizar el trabajo sin hacer uso de variables globales.

Crea un archivo que se llame `funciones.bd.php` con este contenido:

```
<?php
/**
 * Establece la conexión con la base de datos y finaliza la ejecución
 * en caso de error.
 *
 * @return resource Recurso asociado a la conexión MySQLi
 */
function conectar() {
  $conexion = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'vasco');
  /* Presuponemos PHP >= 5.3 si usas fetch_all */
  if ($conexion->connect_error !== null) {
    die($conexion->connect_error);
  }
  if ($conexion->set_charset('utf8') === false) {
    die($conexion->error);
  }
  return $conexion;
}

/**
 * Cierre la conexión MySQLi y devuelve el resultado.
 *
 * @param resource $conexion Recurso de conexión MySQLi
 *
 * @return boolean Estado del cierre de la conexión
 */
function desconectar($conexion) {
  /* Forma correcta de cerrar la conexión */
  return $conexion->close();
}
```

De esta manera, si tienes problemas de conexión, te aparecerán por pantalla y detendrán la ejecución del resto de tu aplicación.

Y esta forma correcta de usar el archivo anterior:

```
/* Incluimos una única vez la definición de funciones de MySQLi */
require_once 'funciones.bd.php';

/* Forma de realizar el trabajo */
$conexion = conectar();
/* Obtenemos los periodos introduciendo como parámetro la conexión MySQLi */
$periodos = muestraPeriodos($conexion);
/* A partir de aquí podemos trabajar con los datos de periodos */
/* ... */
/* Tras terminar el trabajo con la base de datos cerramos la conexión */
desconectar($conexion);


/**
 * Obtiene todos los registros de periodos.
 *
 * @param resource $conexion Recurso de conexión MySQLi
 *
 * @return array Matriz asociativa con todos los registros
 */
function muestraPeriodos($conexion) {
  /* Realizamos la consulta SQL */
  $respuesta = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM periodos");
  /* En caso de error terminamos (tabla no existente, por ejemplo) */
  if ($respuesta === false) {
    die($conexion->error);
  }
  /* Obtenemos los datos y liberamos la memoria asociada al resultado */
  $resultado = $respuesta->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  $respuesta->free();
  /* Una vez liberados los recursos podemos devolver el resultado */
  return $resultado;
}
```

De esta manera sólo se incluirá una única vez la definición de las funciones de conexión y desconexión a tu base de datos. También sabrás qué ha ocurrido con la consulta y la ejecución de tu aplicación tampoco continuará en caso de error.

He eliminado la necesidad de mantener una variable global llamada `$conexion`, pero como puedes ver en el ejemplo, tendrás que hacer las llamadas a tus funciones enviando como parámetro el recurso de la conexión.

Espero que esto solucione tus problemas.

Comment: muchas, gracias, ya lo cambie, pero marca lo siguiente ahora: 
1)Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in::   $respuesta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM periodos");
2)Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_all() on null in:: return $respuesta->fetch_all();

Comment: Te recomiendo encarecidamente que dejes de usar variables globales. Nunca sabes en qué ámbito o en qué otra zona de tu código pueden ser modificadas. Ese mensaje en particular significa que la variable `$conexion` ha dejado de contener un recurso válido asociado a una conexión MySQLi y, en su lugar, podría estar almacenando cualquier cosa. Voy a editar mi respuesta para mostrarte la forma "correcta" de hacerlo evitando ese mal hábito.

Comment: De acuerdo, muchas gracias, al manejar las funciones de ese modo->query o ->fetch_all: no es necesario manejar todo orientado a objetos, o si?

Comment: Usando ese método estás usando la interfaz orientada a objetos de MySQLi, pero eso no implica que tu código deba ser orientado a objetos. Tú puedes seguir usando programación funcional (basada en definición y llamada a funciones) sin ningún problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias saludos